# Match facebook campaign objective with insights actions types

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

Facebook campaigns have an objective among [those listed here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group#Creating) (`PAGE_LIKES`, `VIDEO_VIEWS`, etc).

Facebook insights list users actions among [those listed here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/action-specs/v2.5) (`like`, `video_view`, etc, but some are missing, `unlike` for example).

The problem is: objective and actions do not match.
For example, there is a `PAGE_LIKES` objective and a `like` action.

In the [facebook power manager](https://business.facebook.com/ads/manage/powereditor) there is a "Results" column which gives, for each campaign, the user actions count that match the campaign objective (*992 `like` obtained in the picture below*).

[image: Power Manager]

It seems that there is no such things [in the insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group/insights/) (*neither in the api nor in the sdk*), so what is the proper way to identify a campaign conversion count (*named "Results" in the power manager*)?

Do we have to manually maintain `PAGE_LIKES <-> like`? And if it so, what is the correct mapping?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @PJC Nope. The solution I used is still to manually bind objectives to actions (which fails in couple of cases). Facebook ads api is the worst experience I ever add with programming. An api that barely works, a ui that breaks every imaginable rule of usability and a support team that don't understand anything. Paul Bain's answer bellow is a perfect example of that: the guy refers to an attribute in a doc that don't even exists.

Answer (score -2):

I think you're looking at the wrong doc. You should take a look at the [ad insights object reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-insights/):

This lists the field `results` which is defined as:

> The number of actions as a result of your advert. The results you see
>   here are based on your objective.

For example, try this:

```
/<version>/act_<ACT_ID>/campaigns?fields=insights.fields(actions_results,results)
```

Comment: Are you sure a `results` field is there? I am not finding it in the page you've provided. And using the insights api with the results field I get the error `results is not valid for fields param. All valid values are: date_start, ...`

Comment: Strange that you can't see the doc, can you try the example I've added above?

Comment: I see the doc, but the `results` fields is not listed anywhere in it. I don't know where you've found it. 

Your example doesn't work, I get the error `(#803) Cannot query users by their username (campaigns)` (which doesn't make any sense). 

And I'm more looking for a url like `/<version>/<campaign_id>/insights?fields=results`

Comment: sounds like the call you made there was wrong as that error relates to trying to query a user by username, it the URL should look something like:
/v2.5/12312312/insights?fields=results

Comment: Forget that error, for a moment, please. The first issue is that you refer to a field `results` that's not in the doc, where does it comes from?

Comment: "results" should work as Paul indicated... there might be a problem with the doc (the field is showing up for me)... but I think if you fix your call, it should just work...

Comment: @evanwong using the exact call @Paul Bain provided `/<version>/act_<ACT_ID>/campaigns?fields=insights.fields(actions_results,results)` I get `"(#100) actions_results, results are not valid for fields param. All valid values are: date_start...`

Comment: @PaulBain how do we write this query in programming lang (If possible, I'm looking for python)?

Comment: I'm only interested for all campaigns + insights

Comment: @PaulBain this answer does not work in version 2.8 or 2.9 of the API and I cannot find a clear way to get Marketing API to give me the result for the objective.  Is there any documentation around about how this is mapped together?